# Take the number contained in a string (also floating point number)

Tags: r, string

I have the following vector:

```
vec<-c("70,00 mln  €", "20,50 mln €", "400 mila", "400 mila", "400 mila", "100 mila", "50 mila")
```

In `vec`, `mln` means "milions" whereas `mila` means "thousand". I would like to convert this vector in a numeric vector like the following

```
70000000, 20500000, 400000, 400000, 400000, 100000, 50000
```

e.g. 70000000 stands for 70,00 mln, 20500000 stands for 20,50 mln and so on.

I tried with the following:

```
unlist(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", vec)))
```

to take the numeric part of the strings and then multiply by 1000 or 1000000, but I obtained:

```
[1] "70"  "00"  "20"  "50"  "400" "400" "400" "100" "50"
```

Here, `"70"  "00"` should be just `"70"`, `"20"  "50"` should be instead `20.5` (numeric).

**EDIT**
The one above is just an example. The true (longer) vector is the following

```
vec <- c("70,00 mln  €", "20,50 mln €", "7,00 mln €", "1,90 mln €", 
"1,50 mln €", "16,00 mln €", "15,00 mln €", "3,00 mln €", 
"10 mln €", "6,70 mln €", "5,25 mln €", "4,80 mln €", 
"3,68 mln €", "1,19 mln €", "1,00 mln €", "21 mln €", 
"20 mln €", "3 mln €", "2 mln €", "1,95 mln €", "14.5 mln", 
"14.5 mln", "12 mln", "7 mln", "2,32 mln", "21,30 mln", "21 mln", 
"20 mln", "5 mln", "3,5 mln", "2 mln", "2 mln", "1,00 mln €", 
"19,92 mln", "12,70 mln", "8,00 mln", "1 mln", "4,50 mln", "1,95 mln", 
"4,50 mln", "1,95 mln", "1,00 mln €", "10,00 mln €", "2,00 mln €", 
"2 mln", "4,50 mln", "8,00 mln €", "4,90 mln €", "1,00 mln €", 
"400 mila", "400 mila", "400 mila", "100 mila", "50 mila", "600 mila €", 
"500 mila €", "500 mila €", "200 mila €", "600 mila", 
"520 mila", "200 mila", "100 mila", "500 mila €", "300 mila €", 
"200 mila €", "150 mila €", "20 mila €", "700 mila €", 
"500 mila", "500 mila", "600 mila €", "450 mila €", "33 mila €", 
"500 mila €", "700 mila €", "250 mila €", "100 mila €"
)
```

Comment: I believe the `,` would be `.`.  It depends on the locale for parsing.  So, I replaced it to `.` for parsing correctly in the locale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier option is to do the replacement with `e6` and `e3` for `mln` and `mila` after removing the space and other characters and then convert to numeric with `as.numeric`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_replace_all(str_remove_all(chartr(",", ".", vec), 
        "\\s+€|\\s+"), c(mln = "e6", "mila" = "e3")))
```

-output

```
[1] 70000000 20500000   400000   400000   400000   100000    50000
```

---

Or using the updated `vec` in OP's post

```
as.numeric(str_replace_all(str_remove_all(chartr(",", ".", vec), 
         "\\s+€|\\s+"), c(mln = "e6", "mila" = "e3")))
```

-output

```
[1] 70000000 20500000  7000000  1900000  1500000 16000000 15000000  3000000 10000000  6700000  5250000  4800000  3680000  1190000
[15]  1000000 21000000 20000000  3000000  2000000  1950000 14500000 14500000 12000000  7000000  2320000 21300000 21000000 20000000
[29]  5000000  3500000  2000000  2000000  1000000 19920000 12700000  8000000  1000000  4500000  1950000  4500000  1950000  1000000
[43] 10000000  2000000  2000000  4500000  8000000  4900000  1000000   400000   400000   400000   100000    50000   600000   500000
[57]   500000   200000   600000   520000   200000   100000   500000   300000   200000   150000    20000   700000   500000   500000
[71]   600000   450000    33000   500000   700000   250000   100000
```

Comment: Thank you! However, in my case I have a longer vector, I obtained the error: Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Syntax error in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`\s+???|\s+`). Why? I edited my post.

Comment: @Mark I couldn't reproduce the error.  Please see my updated output with your new data

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark Nice to know.  What was the issue? thanks

Comment: The problem was the symbol €. When I saved the R file (using RStudio) the program returned an error by writing me an error message that I had not paid attention to, which referred to ASCII characters. And Rstudio saved my file deleting symbol €. I solved it by prefixing your statement with the  `iconv`  command